# Changing the content of a webpage without refreshing

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

i have volunteered to make a website for my local animal shelter and they wanted one very similar to http://fsasri.com/. i really like what they do with the buttons and how when you click only the center div changes. iv tried to accomplish this many ways using innerhtml and the jquery version i can't remember it off the top of my head. not matter what i do i can't put that much new content in and internet explore pops up with a security warning and won't let the changes happen unless you allow blocked scripts and activeX. help on how you guys would accomplish this effect and ways to avoid this pop up internet explore would help bundles. iv been doing alot of researchs and have had no luck so far

Comment: Is the IE warning happening on a live website, or just in your local testing?

Comment: Post your code in order to be reviewed and / or corrected. [Descriptive jQuery information](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about Ajax.

Comment: just when local testing i havn't gone live with it im still inthe beginning steps

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://path.com/to/page.html" data-ajax>Home</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    var box = $('#loadtodiv');
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-ajax]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success: function(data) {
                box.html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Something like this should do it, providing that the content on the pages is only meant for the boxes, otherwise you'll have to target the element on the page speficically.

Comment: this seems like exactly what i want to do im pretty new to ajax as in i started learning about it today, my question is what would the url link to? and will this pop up a security warning for internet explorer?

Comment: I've never had any issues like that before, can't see why you should have.

Answer (score 0):

The website at the http://fsasri.com uses frames which I really wouldn't recommend due to a lot of security concerns if not used correctly.

What you can do, however, is to change the content of your 'main' div using jQuery's Ajax functions. Your buttons should look something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button" onclick="getPage('home')">Home</a>
```

And with the following function you can make it work properly:

```
<script>    
function getPage(page)
{
   $.ajax({

     type: "GET",
     url: 'www.yourweb.com/' + page + '.html',
     success: function(data) {
          $('#maindiv').html(data);
     }

   });

}
</script>
```

Comment: sorry im very new to ajax, so this will allow me to dictate what i change in the main Div? like putting in paragraphs of text or a google maps

Comment: The example shown above fully changes the content of the maindiv. However, with the use of CSS selectors you can change only certain data in the main div. The following would only change the HTML of the header (h1) element in the maindiv:

$('#maindiv h1').html(data);

Comment: very cool i tried implementing it and there is a definite improvment, my question now is, with the url section do i want to give the url of another html file in the same folder and then that html folder will be exactly what i want the content of the div to be? P.S. i really appreciate  your help

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood you correctly, but yes - URL should be the file that contains the contents of mainDiv for whatever button you have clicked. Note the page paremeter in the function. In any way, I suggest you use the example Daryl provided since it's easier.

Comment: im not gonna lie i like your system better its easyer for me to understand just have one question should this work for firefox and google chrome or just IE?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ASP.net?

Your own VB/C# code will update or change any content of the website page you like to change.

Comment: this seems like a great tool thanks for bringing my attention to it